# lambda and multiple nested ifs in python

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement, lambda, nested

I'm trying to run a series of tests in my dataframe column `energycertificatetest['TOTAL_FLOOR_AREA']` and save the results in a new column `['Bedrooms']`. The below formula kicks up a syntax error but I can't see where am I going wrong. Thanks in advance!

```
energycertificatetest['Bedrooms'] = energycertificatetest['TOTAL_FLOOR_AREA'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x<45 else (2 if 45<x<=65 else 3 if 65<x<=90 else 4 if x>90))
```

Comment: (1) Format the code correctly. (2) Show the full traceback as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function to apply, for example:

```python
def func(x):
    if x<45:
        return 1
    if 45 <= x < 65:
        return 2
    if 65 <= x < 90:
        return 3
    return 4


energycertificatetest['Bedrooms'] = energycertificatetest['TOTAL_FLOOR_AREA'].apply(func)
```

Comment: this data set has over 10 million rows, will this be quick?

Comment: That depends on your definition of "quick". Could take up to a couple of minutes depending on your machine, etc. But if you don't get more than 10 million new rows every hour, I wouldn't worry about speed at this point.